# sprite renderer keeps white color on color change in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, render

I have a sprite in Unity2D. I want to change its color.

```
[SerializeField]
private SpriteRenderer rend;

private void ChangeColor(Color color)
{
    rend.color = color;
}
```

When executing this code the sprite keeps a white color. But when debugging `rend.color` it has changed its color value.

When executing `rend.color = Color.red;` it changes to red.

The colors I pass in as a parameter are

```
    new Color(255, 51, 51) // red
    new Color(51, 173, 255) // blue
    new Color(77, 255, 77) // green
    new Color(255, 255, 77) // yellow
    new Color(0, 0, 0) // black
    new Color(184, 46, 138) // violett
    new Color(255, 153, 51) // orange
    new Color(0, 255, 255) // cyan
    new Color(0, 179, 0) // dark green
    new Color(255, 255, 255) // white
    new Color(51, 102, 153) // dark blue
```

How can I fix this behaviour?